# MySQL Error on uploading .sql file

Tags: mysql, database, import

I am getting this below error when importing database file,

```
#1621 - SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. 
Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value
```

Also tried setting up my.ini

Please help.

Thanks,
Umesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

This error could not be solved I guess, but the workaround to this is to use MySQL command line to import database using source command.

Thanks :)